# rtl8188ce wifi adapter is not detected after installing newest realtek driver

Tags: 12.10, wireless, drivers, 64-bit, realtek

I have the following problem. Since I installed a kernel update yesterday on my ubuntu 12.10 I thought I might check if there is a new realtek driver too for my wifi(8188ce chip is still very unstable in ubuntu).

What i found was a driver released on the 7th of February this year. I downloaded and installed the driver with the result that my wireless adapter ist not recognized by the system anymore.
(http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=48&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#2722)

After untaring it I installed it like that:

```
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo reboot
```

So to resolve that issue I deinstalled it again with:

```
sudo make uninstall
```

But unfortunately my wireless adapter is still unrecognized. I even tried to install the older driver again in the same way but nothing changed.

Any ideas on that problem? I hope I didnt wrecked my wifi adapter.

```
lspci | grep wifi
```

returned

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)
```

When i try to load the driver manually I get this Output:

```
sudo modprobe rtl8192ce 
FATAL: Error inserting rtl8192ce (/lib/modules/3.5.0-25-generic/updates/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192ce/rtl8192ce.ko): Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem. Since the old driver had a lot of problems with the wifi connection stability I added a custom config file which disabled the powersaving mode.
This option seems to be no longer valid for the new driver and stopped the new driver from loading.

If you have the same problem, then go to

```
/etc/modprobe.d/
```

and delete the rtl8192.conf.

After a reboot the driver should be loaded automaticly/you can load it yourself with

```
sudo modprobe rtl8192ce
```